# Eloquent Seeder - only add if data doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, seeding

I have a table called `permissions`; this is like the different roles a user can have. As the project grows, I may add more functionalities, therefore more `permissions` are created.

I have a `PermissionSeeder.php` that I would like to keep on adding the permissions that I add. Then every time a new permission is added, I would like to run the seeder on it. But, the existing entries should not be created.

I was thinking of truncating the table on every update, but then `permission_id` on the other pivot tables will conflict since they are the foreign keys.

This is what I was going to do at the moment:

```
use Permission;
class PermissionSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        $permissions = [...]; // this is the array of ALL permissions that will keep on growing

        foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
            $model = Permission::whereName($permission['name']);
            if ($model->count() <= 0) {
                DB::table('permissions')->insert($permission);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `firstOrCreate($permission)` on your `Permission` model instead? This would eliminate some code for you.

```
foreach($permissions as $permission) {

    Permission::firstOrCreate($permission);

}
```

Keep in mind you'll need to set your `protected $fillable;` attribute inside your model to allow your fields to be mass assigned.

EDIT: You could also store your permissions inside a config file in your project so it's easier to access. Seems like a more natural place to put it rather than static inside the code itself.

EDIT #2: [Mass Assignment Link Here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Straight from laravel docs:

The fillable property specifies which attributes should be mass-assignable. This can be set at the class or instance level.

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = array('first_name', 'last_name', 'email');

}
```

EDIT #3:

I'd also suggest not mixing [fluent](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries) with [eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent) models. You've already included the `Permission` model into your seeder. You should use that instead in case the name of your permissions table changes, so you only need to change the `protected $table;` attribute inside your model.

---

An Example straight from Laravel Docs:

```
// Retrieve the user by the attributes, or create it if it doesn't exist...
$user = User::firstOrCreate(array('name' => 'John'));
```

[Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#insert-update-delete)